# InstallShield 10 vs 11 - is there a reason to migrate

Tags: installshield

Currently we are wondering whether we should move to IS 11 or stay for longer time with IS 10. It will incorporate upgrade of a few crucial boxes so I would like whether, from your point of view, there are some break through technologies in IS 11 so you must have it or we can easily skip it and wait for the next version.

It is used to installation of server application and stand alone client - msi projects.

Comment: Chris's answer already assumes the more recent pair, but it would be good to clarify whether you mean InstallShield X and 11, or InstallShield 2010 and 2011. If you're still on one of the former, I'd get to one of the latter will all haste, for at least the InstallScript engine architecture or better UAC compliance of IS12 and later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the [IS2011 Release Notes](http://www.installsite.biz/en/desc/ix/rn_IS2011_prepro_en.pdf).

There is now DRM on the standalone build.  ( BOOO )

The standlone build can now be purchased ala cart ( YEAH )

There's some Unicode improvements but I don't do localization or use InstallScript anymore.

It says there is improved TFS support but I know IS2010 already registers with VS2010 so I'm not sure what's different there.

Sounds like there have been some improvements in supporting SQL 2008 R2.

More prereqs but you can always write those yourself or download them and use with 2010 if you really need to.

The InstallScript/VBScript editor is improved but I use C#/DTF/WiX anyways.

Improved App-V if you are into that ( I'm not ).

Setup Prereqs finally support using Path Variables to isolate your dependencies for your build.  That would be nice to have since I typically edit these using Notepad++ today.

Ability to author a HyperLink control ( dependency on MSI 5.0 which makes this useless )

Custom Setup.exe icons and resources if you care.  ( Sounds like your stuff is internal )

Prebuild/PostCompression/PostBuild events.  Pre and Post I don't care about the PostCompression has some very interesting use cases for people who need to make MSI's do things IS can't do and have a compressed setup.exe

Expiring setup.exe's  ( if you care )

Import VDPROJ - thought this one had been around for awhile. Maybe it works now? :-)

Unicode support in SQL scripts.   That could be important ( not to me currently )

64bit and .NET 4.0 improvements.  Always welcomed.

IIS  improvements ( always welcomed )

And more.....

OK, now for the part when I give my opinion.  If what you have is working, stick with it.  If you tend to work on alot of projects, have a little money to spend and don't like hitting brick walls on new problems  then take a chance, upgrade and hopefully you'll never see the problems in the first place.

Put it simpler,  we own 2010 and 2011 but are currently only using 2010.